# Moxa 1130I (RS422 to USB)

Tags: 20.04

we are using Moxa 1130I in Ubuntu 18.06LTS, when our Ubuntu computer is restarted(Power OFF and power ON) we get the default value is (port 1) RS485 2W.
These Moxa converters we are using at remote sites. every time port change is not possible .

Please consider our request , and suggest a default  port 2 (RS422)  configuration.

Comment: Please check your details; you mention a *non-existing* release from 2018 (*that is off-topic here*) but have tagged a different release (20.04) from 2020.  Your question details are very unclear.